# Sum slected cell value with another cell in Excel 2016 using macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am preparing a spreadsheet that does certain functions automatically.

I have the following rows:

A, B, C, D, E,F, AF, G, Date, Formatted Date

My purpose is that when I enter values to cells A to F, the sum is automatically displayed in AF and G is the Sub Total. For example, initially if the values of A to F are 1 each then AF is the sum total of A-F and would display 6, G will be 6 itself as the inital value will be 0, so 0+6 = 6, however I want if I change the values of A-F to 2 each, G should take the previous value (which is for example 6) and sum it to the present value of AF (sum of A-F = 12) and change hte cell value of G to 18

I am trying to create a dynamic macro for this function. I have attained everything else except Replacing G with the sum of present value + the present value of AF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my current macro VBA code

```
  Sub FetchDate()
'
' FetchDate Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""mmmm d, yyyy"")"
    End Sub

Sub Sum()
'
' Sum Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-6]:RC[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: What does that code have to do with putting the sum of A:F into AF?

Comment: When is the sum and subtotal operations supposed to happen? You can only put 1 number into 1 cell at a time and as soon as you change one cell, the sum and subtotal changes but it sounds like you want it to happen when all 6 cells in A:F are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Rohith, as I understand your question is how to provide the running sum. Basically you want to add the first sum value to the next sum value. Hopefully this code can help you to resolve your question. Here you just need to store the first sum value to cell or you can store in variable.

```
Sub SumData()

    Range("H1") = Range("G1").Value
    If Range("H1") = "" Then
        Range("G1") = "=Sum(A1:F1)"
        Range("H1") = Range("G1").Value
        Range("G1") = Range("G1").Value
    ElseIf Range("H1") <> "" Then
        Range("G1") = "=Sum(A1:F1)"
        Gvalue = Range("G1").Value
        Hvalue = Range("H1").Value
        sumvalue = Gvalue + Hvalue
        Range("G1") = sumvalue
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for all the support.

Using the concept mentioned above, I made it work using the following code:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1],RC[-2])"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
```